# pip install ortools: No matching distribution - Alpine

Tags: python, pip, alpine-linux, or-tools

In a docker I try to run pip install ortools and it can't be found. Other pip install packages work flawlessly. I use "FROM python:3.6.8-alpine" in my Dockerfile

```
bash-4.4# pip install ortools
Collecting ortools
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ortools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ortools


bash-4.4# pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (19.1.1)
```

**Root cause:**
Gooogle OR tools does not support alpine, since pypi is not supported on alpine

Follow the progress of this issue: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/756

Comment: Download package files and install, That's only the solution

Comment: The most recent release doesn't provide Linux wheels. Have you tried installing the previous release `pip install ortools==7.1.6720`?

Comment: You won't be able to install wheels from PyPI. They are precompiled for glibc-based Linux distros (`manylinux1` spec). Alpine is musl-based, thus none of the platform-specific wheels can be installed for it. You have to build OR-Tools from source, it's the only option with Alpine.

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/ortools/7.1.6722/#files it only has windows releases.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from Alpine to Bullseye because I didn't have a constraint on it.
Note that this can increase image size.