# Installing python package from source in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, or-tools

I am currently using docker-compose to use an instance of Celery, a python queue manager. However, as I expand my code, I want to be able to use Google's OR-tools package. However, you must install OR-tools from source if you are using python-3.6:alpine (as discussed here: [pip install ortools: No matching distribution - Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287742/pip-install-ortools-no-matching-distribution-alpine)). I have tried using a non-alpine version of python, but then I encounter issues with Celery, so I think install from source is the way forward.

I am relatively new to using Docker, so I am having a hard time to make this happen. Simply adding `RUN git clone -b master https://github.com/google/or-tools` and the rest of the commands mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/python/source_linux to the Dockerfile does not work. It says git is not a command, but if I try to install it using `RUN sudo apt install git` it tells me sudo is not a command.

Do I need to add another section to my dockerfile, something like:

```
FROM: ubuntu
RUN git clone -b master https://github.com/google/or-tools
```

If so, what is the correct way of doing this, and ensuring this is linked to the other part of my Dockerfile so I can use OR-tools in the python code?

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD celery -A celeryExample worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info
```

DOCKER-COMPOSE:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  celery: 
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes: 
        - .:/usr/src/app
```

REQUIREMENTS:

```
celery
redis
requests
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close to it, it's fine to grab dependencies from other images in the same execution.
Try the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone -b master https://github.com/google/or-tools
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD celery -A celeryExample worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 0):

> It says git is not a command, but if I try to install it using RUN sudo apt install git it tells me sudo is not a command.

The base-image called `python:3.6-alpine` exposes user "root", which means that sudo is not needed (you are already root). In Docker, you almost never use sudo or login with users with password since it is a hassle and Docker has other ways of dealing with users, e.g. `USER` syntax:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
USER root
# All commands will be run as user root
...
USER foo
# All commands will be run as user foo
...
```

`python:3.6-alpine` does not have `apt`, instead it uses `apk`. Read more about the alpine image here: https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine

Use `RUN apk add git` without sudo:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add git
...
```

> what is the correct way of doing this, and ensuring this is linked to the other part of my Dockerfile so I can use OR-tools in the python code?

I don't know what the correct way is but I would try building the needed dependencies inside the Dockerfile with the base-image that you are using.